# Does Something wrong with the SD card in use refer to an issue with the android software or its an issue realted with the Sd card itself

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card

I recently updated the OS from Jelly bean to Kitkat Android v4.4 and after this update I am not able to download any file from the browser. Every time I try it gives this pop up and the download fails.

I tried even using the Internal memory but still the issue persists.

[image: Something wrong with the SD card in use.Please check if your SD card is available for downloading]

<sub>Screenshot 1 - Something wrong with the SD card in use.Please check if your SD card is available for downloading</sub>

Later when I select the default path then it gives me the below popup.This pop's up  even when I am setting the internal/Primary storage as default
I doubt whether the Android v4.4 kitkat allows storage on the SD card for normal downloads

[image: Due to Android policy there are some restrictions in using secondary storage]

<sub>Screenshot 2 - Due to Android policy there are some restrictions in using secondary storage -</sub>

<sub>(Click to enlarge the screenshot images)</sub>

Comment: Is this problem with "UC Browser" only or with other browsers as well in your device?

Comment: For chrome it gets auto downloaded to the internal memory so can't say exactly